# Apache child pid XXXXX exit signal Segmentation fault

Tags: php, apache, segmentation-fault, debian

I have a problem with Apache 2.2.22 on Debian Wheezy.

On my Symfony 1.4 website, i have this page : http://www.tennisaddict.fr/babolat-tour/dates

And regularly, twice or thrice a day, this page crashes (under Chromium/Chrome : No Data Received) and when I have a look at /var/log/apache2/error.log I can see that an Apache thread/fork is segfaulting.

This seems to only happen on THIS page. The other sites on my dedicated server are working fine.

A simple Apache reload is sufficient to correct the problem.

I'm running on PHP 5.4.4-14.

**PHP modules installed** (by default and third-party) : apc bcmath bz2 calendar Core ctype curl date dba dom ereg exif fileinfo filter ftp gd gettext hash iconv json libxml mbstring mcrypt mhash mysql mysqli openssl pcntl pcre PDO pdo_mysql Phar posix Reflection session shmop SimpleXML soap sockets SPL standard sysvmsg sysvsem sysvshm tokenizer wddx xml xmlreader xmlwriter zip zlib

**Apache modules** : actions alias asis auth_basic auth_digest authn_alias authn_anon authn_dbd authn_dbm authn_default authn_file authnz_ldap authz_dbm authz_default authz_groupfile authz_host authz_owner authz_svn authz_user autoindex cache cern_meta cgi cgid charset_lite dav dav_fs dav_lock dav_svn dbd deflate dir disk_cache dump_io env expires ext_filter file_cache filter headers ident imagemap include info ldap log_forensic mem_cache mime mime_magic negotiation [*pagespeed (currently disabled)*] php5 proxy proxy_ajp proxy_balancer proxy_connect proxy_ftp proxy_http proxy_scgi reqtimeout rewrite setenvif speling ssl status substitute suexec unique_id userdir usertrack vhost_alias

---

**EDIT/SOLUTION (in my case / please read this if you are using APC) :** APC was guilty. I recommend to the other people to choose another PHP accelerator or upgrade PHP to 5.5 that have a native accelerator (via OPcodes caching, like APC). This native accelerator is Zend OPCache, precedently named Zend Optimizer. You can install it on older PHP releases than 5.5. Here a monitoring PHP page for Zend OPCache : https://gist.github.com/ck-on/4959032

Comment: I've had several problems as such and was related to `APC` induced 'White screen of death'. What version of `APC` are you running? Are running the `PECL` version (which is advised)? How much `SHM is allocated to `APC`?

Comment: I'm running APC 1.1.13 installed via PECL. There is 1 SHM segment of 1024M, currently used 135M.

Comment: This is very hard to debug. Try analyzing the apc output at the apc.php page and check for overflows. I ended up using our nagios monitoring tool that does an apache restart automatically if the response is empty for the ominous websites. Can you consider upgrading to the latest version? That is if this issue is really related to APC... Segmentation faults can be caused simply by faulty hardware.

Comment: I see.
Yesterday after my response to your comment, I uninstalled APC and upgraded PHP to version 5.5.12 because it includes by default the Zend OPcache (aka Zend Optimizer) that replaces APC.
Since that, the webpage had not crashed. If think that if this evening the page is still online, I will consider that APC was faulty.

Comment: if it continues to work, then consider an upvote to one of my comments, so other people might find it useful. Alternatively I may post it as an answer.

Comment: Done ! Sorry I forgot that comments can be upvoted. Thanks for your help =)

Comment: No problem. You can also answer and accept your own question. Alternatively you let the person who helped you create an answer and accept that. That way we gain some reputation. :)